# Why do we use 0.23 as the acceptance rate for the Metropolis-Hastings algorithm?

Tags: probability, statistics, markov-chains, bayesian, gibbs-measure

I understand that traditionally the value of 0.23 is suggested for the acceptance rate when monitoring a Metropolis-Hastings algorithm, why is this and what would the effect of having a higher acceptance rate be?

Comment: It still works you just don't converge as fast. I think it has been fine tuned, i'm sure you can find the research articles about it online.